What does the laa (لا) tajweed symbol mean when reciting the Qur'an?
I was always taught that the laa (لا) symbol meant "Never stop here", and that any recitation would need to continue through it as if it was one phrase. So, for example (taken from the break between Surah Ya-Sin 79 and 80)

As I was taught, this would always be recited as "…`aliimullathii…", with no break between it. And that if I do catch myself pausing at that point and needing to continue the recitation, I should always back up a few words so I could properly recite the entire thing without pausing, as otherwise I could inadvertently be changing the meaning of the verse into something Islamically unacceptable.
However, I have come to be told that there is a difference of opinion regarding this mark in the case of it being above a circle, which I was unaware of. It was definitely not how I was taught, and most English-language resources for reading the Qur'an that I can easily dig up (e.g. What are the different punctuation in Quran?) confirm that it just means "Do not stop, period." and don't mention any difference of opinion in that regard.
So the question lies, in the hopes of making this a comprehensive canonical reference, how should the laa (لا) mark be interpreted when reciting the Qur'an? What does it mean, why is it important, and what differences of opinion are there regarding it?

Salam you have seemingly missed What are the different punctuation in the Qur'an? which covers all symbols and signs related to waqf. I just want to add waqf is a topic of ijtihaad. In the waqf usually used in moshafs printed in the Maghreb you won't even find such a rule, there are either permissible waqf symbols or none. In your case it is a simple waqf at the end of the verse.

@Medi1Saif That post has the same issue as everywhere else I had checked, in that it doesn't mention the difference of opinion regarding a lam-alif over a circle that prompted this question in the first place.

so far I only know these two let's say big schools of waqf, I try to learn more about the topic. Note that even in Hafs Moshafs there's a small difference between the Indo-Pak Mushafs (and Turkish ones) and those of Medina/Azhar.

لا means do not pause.
ة or ࣢ or ۝ etc. means pause, as it indicates the end of the verse in some recitations.
If only لا is present then you should not pause. However when they are both present at the same place then this indicates that there is disagreement on whether or not to pause. In this case it is valid to do either.
In this specific verse if you pause it will be recited as "aleem ... aladhee". If you do not pause it will be "aleemuniladhee". The first one is permissible, indeed if you listen to audio recitations of this verse they will usually be with a pause.

Reference:
See the appendices of some of the Indo-Pak mushafs which contain the combined symbol.
For example the one published by King Fahd Complex for the Printing of the Holy Quran has this near the end:


لا means 'no'. This sign is sometimes used above a verse ending sign and sometimes within the text of the verse. If it is within the text of the verse then you should never pause. If it is above the sign of a verse ending then there is disagreement. Near some one should pause and near others one should not pause. However regardless of whether one pauses or not the meaning is not made problematic. Pausing is only not to be done when this is inside the text of the verse.

Similarly you can see another one here:

